# Set calendar as a default within in device through iPad App

Tags: ios

I want to set my calendar as a default within iPad, through my iPad app ????
 Actually I am creating the new Calendar through App and want to set that calendar should be set as default at that time when I create it.How can I do it ??

Comment: Sorry, but i think (and hope) that this is not possible. This has to be under user's complete control.